# How to remove left over empty small partitions? (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

After unistalling Ubuntu 17 from my laptop, left me with 3 very small pertitions which they added 3 extra letters to my drives. I am unable to delete them format them or anything from windows D management, is there another method to remove them please? This is how my HD is partitioned: 323MB, 260MB, 128MB, C:\687GB NTFS, F:904MB NTFS, G:450MB NTFS, H:9.42GB Recovery NTFS.
The NTFS partitions are from Windows, but the first 3 are Linux left overs. I'll appreciate your help.